# Show that $(I − Q)^{−1} $= $Q^2 + Q+ I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $Q\in M_n (\mathbb{R})$ Assume that $Q^3 = [0] $ show that $ (I − Q)^{−1} = Q^2 + Q + I$.

What I tried: I tried to use $(I-Q)(I-Q)^{-1} = I$ and use that to manipulate the left side of the equation, but that didn't work.

Comment: Calculate  $(I-Q)(Q^2+Q+1)$.

Comment: @AndreNicholas Why are you allowed to do that, though?

Comment: You can always multiply matrices (if they are both square and the same size). Try it, you will like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(I-Q)(Q^2+Q+I)=Q^2+Q+I-Q^3-Q^2-Q=I$ because we assume $Q^3=0$.  From that it follows that $(I-Q)^{-1}=Q^2+Q+I$.  Since you say you tried this, maybe you made some error (I hate it when that happens).